# How to add supabase nativescript

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, supabase

I am trying to build a supabase nativescript app. I cannot work with the detection or declare with require.
I made a login already. It's working. But the supabase is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this Nativescript plugin https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@triniwiz/nativescript-supabase/ using the Nativescript CLI, which is a wrapper around the [official package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@supabase/supabase-js) :

```sh
ns plugin add @triniwiz/nativescript-supabase
```

and then import it like this in your code :

```js
import {createClient} from '@triniwiz/nativescript-supabase';
```